# STM32CubeIDE HAL_Delay not working

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I am trying to toggle the GPIO port 8 with:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_Delay(1000);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

When I debug the application I can see, that the `HAL_Delay` does not work. I'm not sure if I missed a configuration option in the STM32CubeIDE to enable the SysTick.

Does anyone use STM32CubeIDE and can give me a hint?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the code executing in ISR?

Comment: I don't think so. But I did not find the right option to enabel it

Comment: The problem is that SYSTICK only works while not debugging. If you run it works fine, but if you step through the code, the interrupt is not called which updates the SYSTICK counter. It's very annoying indeed.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Is this a general "problem" with stm32 mcus or just with STM32Cube Ide?

Comment: "`HAL_Delay` does not work" is not much of a problem description. Does your code get stuck in `HAL_Delay`, or does it appear to simply skip over `HAL_Delay`?

Comment: I think it is a problem with STM32Cube, but I don't know if other IDEs (or code generated by such IDEs) also use SYSTICK. I think the only problem is while stepping through code, when just 'running' between breakpoints it should work.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Just running the code does also not work. I will try to use timer1 for the systick perhaps that works.

Comment: Hmm, than I also don't know by heart.

Comment: If you are debugging, it should not be too hard to view the systick registers to confirm if systick is configured or not. Check to see if the period register has been configured.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. I have a jumper on my board to select the boot mode. I did not connect any of the pins (so no connection to VSS or VCC). This somehow resulted in the error described above. As soon as I set the jumper to connect Pin BOOT to VCC the clock started to work.